# Why doesn't Windows utilize readyboost devices?

Tags: cache, readyboost

I have a 4 GB Verbatim USB 2.0 Flash drive plugged into one of the rear USB ports on my computer. Windows detects this as a device that can be used for ReadyBoost, and I have selected that the operating system dedicates the drive to ReadyBoost- And yet, I notice no speed improvements whatsoever. According to the Properties window of the device, 3557 MB is being used for ReadyBoost, and the remainder of the space on the device is just a couple of .PSDs from work that I never open, so I don't think the issue is that there isn't enough space to use on the drive.

The problem isn't that my computer has no need for such extra cache space, either, as I work with software such as Adobe Premiere which require literally all of the caching space they can get. Plus, I have worked with said software on other computers that have the same configuration in terms of RAM and ReadyBoost, and there is a preformance improvement- The software renders video faster, etc- So why am I not getting this on my system? I Do mean to upgrade my internal RAM in the future, but as of the time I wrote this, I do not have the means.

Is there any reason why my system isn't utilizing Readyboost?

**EDIT:** I should probably note that my internal HDD is a 2 TB 7500 RPM connected with 4 Gb/S SATA to the Motherboard. Premiere has its own 80 GB HDD of the same speed and connection as my main drive, however I only use it to save projects and use it for storing footage that I'm working on. Strangely enough Premiere still seems to be caching to my main HDD which... Doesn't make the most sense.

Comment: What kind of speed increase are you looking for? Most harddisks, even slow ones, will run far faster than the 35MB/s that a USB2.0 drive will be capped at. It's certainly not going to feel like you put an SSD in the system or anything. Premiere caching on your main drive makes perfect sense - your 7200 RPM drives are going to run at more than 100MB/s depending on how recent they are. Much, much faster than your USB stick. (Not to mention, apps like Premiere don't use readyboost/memory for a cache, they use scratch files.)

Comment: Your system actually is utilizing ReadyBoost.  The problem is you bottlekneck isn't the amount of system memory.  You don't indicate how the configuration of those "other" computers differ from yours.

Comment: well, The computers at my work have quad core 3.2 GHz i5s as their processors, with 4GB internal RAM and 4GB Readyboost. Same enough Hard Drive configuration, too. Only difference between the two is that my computer has 2 Intel Xeon octo-cores clocked at 3 GHz each. Logically my computer should preform faster.

Comment: @darthAndroind Had no idea premiere doesn't cache to readyboost or memory.

Comment: @DarthAndroid "Most harddisks, even slow ones, will run far faster than the 35MB/s that a USB2.0 drive will be capped at." EXACTLY! So I often ask myself, "why would Microsoft even spend the time to introduce the ReadyBoost feature?" - as it would only provide a performance increase on a small number of systems that happen to have USB 2.0 systems and very slow hard drives, correct?

Comment: @dtmland Because that's only when talking about sequential bulk data. If you're talking about R/W IOPS, an SSD attached over USB 2.0 is going to run circles around a spinning platter disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide evidence that the USB drive is being used for ReadyBoost, but then wonder why it's not. Perhaps you are actually wondering why it's not resulting in a speed increase?

If so, this is probably because USB2 is [capped at about 35 MB/sec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0), likely slower than your other drives. It could also be that your workload does not lend itself to easy caching, or that 3.5 GB doesn't make much difference. But fundamentally, you are unlikely to see a difference with a USB 2 drive used as a cache.